# how can I get my sleeping cycle to normal again?

Tags: sleep, sleep-cycles

in my job I have no official known work hours ,when they call I have to go to work no matter what hour it is (should've red the contract before I signed it right :-D ),this make me lose my sleeping cycle and I end up always sleeping during day and can't sleep the night ,my way to fix this is to deprive my self from sleep for 36 hours that way I will sleep during night ,but I always end up loosing that cycle again ,any good way to reverse sleeping cycle to normal without depriving my self from sleep ? is the use of some sleeping pills recommended ?

Comment: I believe that this may be a duplicate of [Reversing sleep cycle](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1101/reversing-sleep-cycle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many sleeping pills are addictive.
Many non-addictive sleeping pills can be mentally addictive.

If you do not mind using sleeping pills for the rest of your life, then that is a perfectly fine choice.

Otherwise, you may want to consider other options first.

Exercise will help. Use up your energy and your body will WANT sleep. Exercise is key to your body's cycles.
Your circadian rhythm (sleeping cycle) is largely affected by light. Particularly, artificial light gives off a lot of light in the frequency range that causes your body to think its NOT time to sleep and will screw up your cycles. When you know you have time to sleep, stay away from staring at computer screens as much as possible.
Stay away from stimulants. i.e. caffeine or whatever else you may use throughout the day/night.

The huge factor here is that you said you have no official known work hours and you go in whenever they ask you to. 
If that means that you never know when you might have a good 6-8 hours of sleeping time, then there really is no way to "fix your cycles" since it is a constantly moving unknown. Sleeping pills *MAY* be the only realistic answer in that case. 
However, if you are able to figure out times when you know you will be off work for a certain number of hours more often than not, then you have a good chance of trying to fix your sleeping cycle.

[Light level and duration of exposure determine the impact of self-luminous tablets on melatonin suppression](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0003687012001159)

[Evening use of light-emitting eReaders negatively
affects sleep, circadian timing, and
next-morning alertness](http://www.pnas.org/content/112/4/1232.full.pdf)

[The Sleep and Technology Use of Americans: Findings from the National Sleep Foundation's 2011 Sleep in America Poll](http://www.aasmnet.org/jcsm/ViewAbstract.aspx?pid=29249)

Comment: "Many non-addictive sleeping pills can be mentally addictive. If you do not mind using sleeping pills for the rest of your life, then that is a perfectly fine choice." You really need to back up such statements. It may be "common knowledge", but a lot of "common knowledge" (like drinking 8 glasses of water per day) is not true at all. Look up melatonin and suvorexant, for example.

Comment: What about 8 glasses of water is common knowledge? Just unsure what you mean. 
What is your take, pertaining to melatonin and suvorexant?
Do you deem it as non-addictive, both physically and mentally?

Comment: the Other options are valuable ,I mean I use computer alot specially at the after noon and night didn't know it was waking up my body because I use it for the opposite (I use computer to make my self tired !)  ,still they are a better option than pills ,I mean those pills will force me to sleep in a way to shutdown I think there is an effect for the long term can't afford the risk ,I will only if the risk of sleep deprivation is higher